# Limit columns from list of tuples while dataframe creation

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

How to limit columns while creating df from list of tuples?

**Expected Input:**

```
data = [('a',11,111),
        ('b',22,222),
        ('c',33,333)]
```

**Expected Output:**

```
   A   B
0  a  11
1  b  22
2  c  33
```

I wrote:

```
pd.DataFrame([(x[0], x[1]) for x in data], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

BUT is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Create the df and then slice, `pd.DataFrame(data).iloc[:,:2]`

Comment: i don't think your current solution is in-elegant at all, maybe use slicing instead, `pd.DataFrame([i[:2] for i in data],columns=['A','B'])`

Comment: @Datanovice Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I think we can do `from_records`

```
pd.DataFrame.from_records(data,exclude=[2], columns=['A','B',2])
Out[27]: 
   A   B
0  a  11
1  b  22
2  c  33
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
In [1461]: df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])[['A','B']]
In [1463]: df
Out[1463]: 
   A   B
0  a  11
1  b  22
2  c  33
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
pd.DataFrame(map(itemgetter(0,1),data))

    0   1
0   a   11
1   b   22
2   c   33
```